# Можно ли периодически отправлять сообщения боту telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot

Собственно сабж. Есть одна текстовая игра - бот-телеграм. Чтобы получать золото, нужно каждые пять минут писать ему сообщение. Можно ли автоматизировать этот процесс? Подскажите пути решения

Comment: А какие пути решенния вы уже попробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер, предлагаю сделать класс со статическим методом который принимает сообщение, а внутри сделать бесконечный цикл в котором будет отправляться сообщение и останавливаться поток выполнения программы на 5 минут, а после возобновляться.(Это в случае ООП)

В случае функционального программирования - делаем функцию по тому же принципу, только вызывать ее придется тоже в цикле.

Comment: telegram api позволяет отправлять сообщения боту?

Comment: Конечно, отправка сообщений один из самых главных функционалов соц. сетей